# Does there exist a set $\{ \Omega\mid \aleph_0<{\rm card}(\Omega)<2^{\aleph_0} \}$?

Tags: set-theory

I am a beginner in set theory, so if this question is strange, I apologise. As well known, from the consequence about the continuum hypothesis it is provable in ZFC that "If ${\rm Con(ZFC)}$, then it is independent of ZFC that whether there exists a set $\Omega%$ satisfying $\aleph_0<{\rm card}(\Omega)<2^{\aleph_0}$." In other words, there are both models of ZFC where there exists a set $\Omega%$ satisfying $\aleph_0<{\rm card}(\Omega)<2^{\aleph_0}$ and models where there does not exist a set $\Omega%$ satisfying it. On this basis, when I think about a set $\{ \Omega \mid \aleph_0<{\rm card}(\Omega)<2^{\aleph_0} \}$, it goes over my head. As I understand it the following statements are provable in ZFC, e.g. there exists this set, (if ZFC is consistent then) the statement that the cardinality of this set is not $0$ is independent of ZFC, and the cardinality of this set is greater than or equal to $0$. Is this correct? I'd appreciate if you could answer the question.

Comment: I think you are right in the first part, Given CH, the set would be empty, cardinality zero. If CH fails, I don't think the set exists. Intuitively it would have cardinality strictly greater than zero, but I suspect it's a Proper Class, in that case. Even a set containing all the sets with card(X) = 1, does not exist.

Comment: If $\Omega$ ranges of all *sets* (and then, a weird choice of variable), then your comprehension (= set builder) is a proper class. If $\Omega$ ranges over ordinals only, then it's a set, one which every model of ZFC contains its version of: by the powerset and comprehension axioms it's guaranteed to exist. It's empty in a model iff CH holds in that model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a model of ZF(C) where the continuum hypothesis holds, the class $\{ \Omega \mid \aleph_0 < card(\Omega) < 2^{\aleph_0} \}$ is empty. Hence it is a set, namely the empty set.

On the other hand, in a model of ZF(C) where the continuum hypothesis does not hold (i.e. where it is false), the class $C := \{ \Omega \mid \aleph_0 < card(\Omega) < 2^{\aleph_0} \}$ is not empty. But now we can show that it is a proper class (as mentioned by Michael Carey in the comments). So $C$ is not a set in this case.

As a proof, I claim that if $C$ is non-empty, then $\bigcup C$ is the class of all sets. Let $x$ be any set and $y \in C$ (which exists by non-emptyness of $C$).
If $x \in y$ then we are done, as $x \in \bigcup C$ follows directly. Otherwise $x \notin y$.
Because $\aleph_0 < card(y)$, there must be some $z \in y$.
Define $w := (y \setminus \{z\}) \cup \{x\}$. We can find a bijection between $y$ and $w$ by taking the identity on $y \setminus \{z\}$ and mapping $z \mapsto x$. Therefore $card(w)=card(y)$ and $w \in C$. By construction $x \in w$ so we obtain $x \in \bigcup C$ as claimed.

The same proof that $C$ is a proper class works, whenever $C$ is a non-empty class only defined in terms of the cardinality of its elements.

Comment: Ah, I find it rather elegant that $C$ exists as a set in the present of $\text{CH}$, but does not exist as a set in the absence of $\text{CH}$, because $\text{CH}$ is a statement about the *non*-existence of sets, which makes this result slightly counterintuitive.

Comment: To be precise, if $C$ is not a set if $\mathrm{CH}$ is *false*. If we know nothing about $\mathrm{CH}$ in our model, we simultaneously know nothing about $C$.

Comment: That is true. Then by "absence of $\text{CH}$" I should really say in the presence of $\neg\text{CH}$.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments or answers. Got it, I didn't thought the possibility that $C$ becomes a proper class. it is interesting that depending on the choice of a model $C$ vary the empty set or a proper class.